# Why won't gradle run from within a jenkins job

Tags: hibernate, jenkins, gradle

I am trying to setup a build on our Jenkins server to run a fork of the hibernate-core project.

I have been able to get Jenkins to do the git clone to get a local repository from my github fork, but when Jenkins tries to run the 'gradlew' command it fails.

When running this script directly from the checked out folder the build runs as expected, but when launching the script via Jenkins it fails.

The job is configured as a Freestyle configuration with the build step setup as an "execute shell" step.

The build step runs the following command.

`./gradlew clean test install buildReleaseBundles uploadArchives --debug --stacktrace`

It seems that the gradlew script is being executed but within the gradle Download class something goes wrong.

My build script outputs the following:

```
Building on master
Checkout:workspace / /data/hudson/jobs/hibernate-envers-stevemac/workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@63e4f703
Using strategy: Default
Last Built Revision: Revision 7cdb4c829f28c5b029a3d43f50a54d4c89fc9665 (origin/Branch_4.0.0.Final)
Checkout:workspace / /data/hudson/jobs/hibernate-envers-stevemac/workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@63e4f703
Fetching changes from 1 remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from https://stevemac007@github.com/stevemac007/hibernate-core.git
Commencing build of Revision 7cdb4c829f28c5b029a3d43f50a54d4c89fc9665 (origin/Branch_4.0.0.Final)
Checking out Revision 7cdb4c829f28c5b029a3d43f50a54d4c89fc9665 (origin/Branch_4.0.0.Final)
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/tomcat6-tmp/hudson9191971611159378903.sh
+ ./gradlew clean test install buildReleaseBundles uploadArchives --debug --stacktrace
Downloading http://repo.gradle.org/gradle/distributions/gradle-1.0-milestone-3-bin.zip

Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/tomcat6/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.0-milestone-3-bin.zip.part (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:194)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:145)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:46)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:37)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:54)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Wrapper.execute(Wrapper.java:80)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:37)
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As normal with this sort of question, the actual asking of it caused me to re-read the message correctly and look for the result.

And in this case all of the information I needed was there.

`FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/tomcat6/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.0-milestone-3-bin.zip.part (No such file or directory)`

The issue is the user that runs the Jenkins job was not the same user I was running the job on the server as, and the job didn't have write access to the /usr/share/tomcat6/ folder.

Granting write access for the tomcat6 user to /usr/share/tomcat6 allowed this job to run.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the Gradle plugin for Jenkins. Works like a charm. Go to https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gradle+Plugin for more details.